# Как вызвать метод класса из ArrayList

Tags: java, полиморфизм

Есть следующий код

```
public interface Archer {
    public double shoot();
    public void damage(int damage);
    public void health();
}

public interface Warrior {
    public double attack();
    public void damage(int damage);
    public void health();
}

public class ElfArcher implements Archer  {
    public int heals = 100;
    public boolean ellitGroup = false;

    public double shoot() {
        if(ellitGroup == true)
            return 5*1.5;
        else return 5;
    }

    public void damage(int damage) {
        this.heals -= damage;
    }

    public void health() {
        System.out.println("остаток здоровья" + this.heals);
    }
}

public class ElfWarrior implements Warrior {
    public int heals = 100;
    public boolean ellitGroup = false;

    public double attack() {
        if(ellitGroup == true)
            return 15*1.5;
        else return 15;
    }

    public void damage(int damage) {
        this.heals -= damage;
    }

    public void health() {
        System.out.println("остаток здоровья" + this.heals);
    }
}

public class ElfSquad {
    ArrayList squad = new ArrayList();
    Archer arc1,arc2,arc3;
    Warrior war4,war5,war6,war7;
    public ElfSquad() {
    }


    public Archer createArcher() {
        return new ElfArcher();
    }

    public Warrior createWarrior() {
        return new ElfWarrior();
    }

    public ArrayList createSquad() {
        squad.add(createArcher());
        squad.add(createArcher());
        squad.add(createArcher());
        squad.add(createWarrior());
        squad.add(createWarrior());
        squad.add(createWarrior());
        squad.add(createWarrior());

        return squad;
    }

    public void atackedEnemySquad(int who, int damage) {
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ElfSquad squadAliance = new ElfSquad();
        ArrayList test = squadAliance.createSquad();
        test.get(0).shoot();
        test.get(1).damage(15);
        test.get(2).damage(24);
        test.get(3).health();
        test.get(3).attack();
    }
}
```

Как вызвать методы из интерфейсов shoot(), attack(),damage(),health() 
следующим образом

```
test.get(0).shoot();
test.get(4).attack();
test.get(4).health();
```

Или предложите другой способ его вызвать.

Comment: метод надо вызвать для каждого объекта в списке или для одного?

Comment: Если вы добавляете объекты разных классов и хотите вызвать метод у каждого объекта вам нужно создать базовый класс или интерфейс с общим методом например attack() который будет реализовывать свою логику в каждом отдельном классе. После этого нужно создать список и в джинерике указать интерфейс который реализуют классы List<Unit> unitList = new ArrayList<>()

Comment: Как сделать что бы была возможность вызывать методы интерфейсов 
test.get(0).shoot();
test.get(4).attack();
test.get(4).health();

Comment: @Денис создайте базовый интерфейс и унаследуйте его в Archer и Warrior который будет иметь метод attack() или какое вам больше нравится.

Comment: не делайте поля объекта публичными - это идет в разрез с принципами ООП. не ставьте `public` у методов интерфейса - они по умолчанию публичные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходим общий интерфейс с необходимыми вам методами от которог унаследованы другие интерфейсы, после этого вы можете писать классы реализовывая эти интерфейсы и тогда можно будет при проходе в цикле или еще где либо вызывать этот метод. Может я не очень понятно объясняю, тогда вам лучше почитать про полиморфизм и наследование.

```
interface IBase{
   void common();
}


interface IA extends IBase{
    void sayA();
}


interface IB extends IBase{
    void sayB();
}

class A implements IA{
    public void common() {
        System.out.println("Common A");
    }

    public void sayA() {
        System.out.println("Say A");
    }
}


class B implements IB{
    public void common() {
        System.out.println("Common B");
    }

    public void sayB() {
        System.out.println("Say B");
    }
}

public class Launch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<IBase> list = new ArrayList<IBase>();
        list.add(new A());
        list.add(new A());
        list.add(new A());
        list.add(new A());
        list.add(new A());
        list.add(new B());
        list.add(new B());
        list.add(new B());
        list.add(new B());
        list.add(new B());

        for (IBase base : list) {
            base.common();
        }

        list.get(0).common();
        list.get(7).common();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение и пример!!! Великолепно объясняете!!!